# Ejecutar crons automaticamente mediante una clase en Django

Tags: python, django

estoy trabajando en un proyecto conjunto y me han pedido que cree una clase para ejecutar un cron cada minuto que se dedique a ejecutar otros crons que ya estarán configurados en un futuro.

La duda que tengo es si hay algún comando que ejecute el cron automáticamente, he dejado indicado comentado en cada uno de los puntos que se debería ejecutar, ya que en la clase de donde extrae la información para ejecutar el cron hay opciones de ejecutar inmediatamente, más tarde o programado(este último no está acabado).

A continuación os dejo el cron creado y las clases que utiliza:

actualizar_tareas.py (el cron en el que estoy trabajando)

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from pip._vendor import requests
from core.GestionTareasProgramadas.models.programador import Programador
from core.GestionTareasProgramadas.models.proceso import Proceso
from core.cron import CronJobBase, Schedule


class CronEjecutor(CronJobBase):
    RUN_EVERY_MINS = 0  # every minutes
    schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
    code = 'Ejecutar Crons'  # a unique code

    def do(self):
        ahora = datetime.now()
        procesos = Programador.objects.filter(estado == 'programado')
        for proceso in procesos:
            if proceso.programado == 'immediatamente':
                #ejecutar cron
            elif proceso.programado == 'mas_tarde':
                if proceso.fecha_inicio == ahora.day and proceso.hora_inicio == ahora.hour:
                    #ejecutar cron
            else:
                i=0
                for i in proceso.intervalo:
                    #ejecutar cron
                    datetime.sleep(proceso.frequencia)
```

programador.py (principales clases a las que llama)

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

from core.GestionTareasProgramadas.models.proceso import Proceso
from core.GestionTareasProgramadas.models.options import GestionTareasProgramadasOptionList



class Programador(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    organizacion = models.CharField(verbose_name='Organización', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    estado = models.CharField(verbose_name='Estado', max_length=20, choices=GestionTareasProgramadasOptionList.estado_choices, default="no_programado", null=False, blank=False)
    activo = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Activo', null=False, blank=False, default=False)
    proceso_ID = models.ForeignKey(Proceso, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Proceso ID', null=False)
    programado = models.CharField(verbose_name='Programado', max_length=20, choices=GestionTareasProgramadasOptionList.programado_choices, default='immediatamente', null=False, blank=False)
    fecha_inicio = models.DateField(verbose_name='Fecha inicio', null=True, blank=True)
    hora_inicio = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Hora inicio', null=True, blank=True)
    frecuencia = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Frecuencia', null=True, blank=True)
    intervalo = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Intervalo', null=True, blank=True)
    fecha_fin = models.DateField(verbose_name='Fecha fin', null=True, blank=True)
    hora_fin = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Hora fin', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.frecuencia

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
        verbose_name = "Programador"
        verbose_name_plural = "Programadores"
        db_table = 'core_programador_programador'
```

options.py(incluye las choices de la anterior clase)

```
from django.db import models

class GestionTareasProgramadasOptionList(models.Model):
    programado_choices = (('immediatamente', 'Ejecutar immediatamente'), ('mas_tarde', 'Ejecutar más tarde'), ('programado', 'Programado'))
    estado_choices = (('programado', 'Programado'), ('no_programado', 'No programado'))

    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

proceso.py

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class Proceso(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False, unique=True, verbose_name='Uuid')
    organizacion = models.CharField(verbose_name='Organización', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    activo = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Activo', null=True)
    indetificador = models.CharField(verbose_name='Identificador', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nombre', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    nombre_clase = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nombre Clase', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
        verbose_name = "Proceso"
        verbose_name_plural = "Procesos"
        db_table = 'core_programador_proceso'
```

Comment: No has intentado herramientas como [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/index.html) o algo asi? Hay hartos [tutoriales en internet](https://medium.com/@hellbreak/how-to-run-periodic-tasks-in-celery-28e1abf8b458)

Comment: Solo puedo utilizar herramientas de python/django.

Comment: Esto puedes lograrlo con python-rq y django-rq hay algo de material en internet que te explican como hacerlo solo que necesitarias ejecutar el servidor redis para programarlas.